# How can I remove cells mentioning containing "takehome" or similar phrases?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to remove all jobs mentioning "takehome", "take home", "take-home", etc. from this sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UgiKHokV3bpeuCF4lhgc9aQisE3c86OyVjZeats9u24/edit#gid=0

This code does not do anything:

```
function myFunction() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1UgiKHokV3bpeuCF4lhgc9aQisE3c86OyVjZeats9u24");
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = data.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
     if (data[i][0].includes('takehome')) {
     sheet.deleteRow(i); 
     }
  }
}
```

How can I do this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the lines:

```
if (data[i][0].includes('takehome')) {
sheet.deleteRow(i);
```

with:

```
if (data[i][0].match(/take([^a-z]*)home/i)) {
sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
```

`[^a-z]*` means any (or none) symbols except the alphabetical ones from 'a' to 'z'.

`i` means to ignore case.

---

Just in case, the full code is here:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (data[i][0].match(/take([^a-z]*)home/i)) sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That deletes many rows but not the right ones for some reason.

Comment: I doubt it. Show an example of the row that was wrong deleted.

Comment: You can color the cell instead of delete, with the line: `sheet.getRange('A'+(i+1)).setBackground('yellow');` and see. It colors 453 cells and I see no problem among of them.

Answer (score 0):

I made this change and it worked:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1UgiKHokV3bpeuCF4lhgc9aQisE3c86OyVjZeats9u24");
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rem = ["take home", "takehome", "take-home"];//you can add other options in this array
  rem.forEach(s => {
    sh.createTextFinder(s).matchEntireCell(false).findAll().forEach(r => {
      sh.deleteRow(r.getRow());
      //Logger.log(r.getRow())
    })
  })

}
```

Another Possibility:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.createTextFinder("take.*home").useRegularExpression(true).matchEntireCell(false).findAll().sort((a,b) => b.getRow() - a.getRow()).forEach(r => {
    sh.deleteRow(r.getRow());
    //Logger.log(r.getRow())
  })
}
```

The latter one will handle just about everything that can be between take and home including multiple characters.  It will remove all of these:

```
take   home
take-home
takehome
take_home help
takehome
take and add a bunch of charactors home
```